# Space issue with query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using query_string with standard analyzer

I have data :-

```
{ "foo":"John Smith" }

{ "foo":"Smith John" }

{ "foo":"John Smith Hi How U" }

{ "foo":"Beacon" }

{ "foo":"Demo hei Device" }
```

But When I am using this query with query_string :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "foo:John a"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Result should be :-

```
{ "foo":"John Smith" }

{ "foo":"Smith John" }

{ "foo":"John Smith Hi How U" }
```

Actual Responce :-

```
{ "foo":"John Smith" }

{ "foo":"Smith John" }

{ "foo":"John Smith Hi How U" }

{ "foo":"Beacon" }

{ "foo":"Demo hei Device" }
```

Could anybody tell , this extra result data ("foo":"Beacon") , { "foo":"Demo hei Device" } is coming ?

I think , query_string considering three token :-
1)John
2)a
3) (SPACE)

Please how could I make like that query_string will consider only two token 
1)john 2)a

Actually some time it doest not consider Space as third token !

Comment: Try:  "foo:\"John a\""

Comment: I have tried , no data coming than

Comment: Maybe: "foo:\"John\"" ? Data no coming because you dont have any John a...

Comment: I chekced and I dont see anywhere in result term like John a

Comment: @VijayGupta What is the mapping for `foo` field?

Comment: "analyzer": "standard"

Comment: Can you try `"query": "foo:(John a)"` ? btw how many fields do you have in single document?

Comment: Now its working , thanks

Comment: Great! It seems you have more than one filed in your index!

Comment: Sorry , Did not get what is filed in index ? any specific reason why it was happening .

Comment: `field` in index is like a column in SQL table. So here `foo` is one field. if you have more than one field in your index then `"query":"foo:John a"` works differently but when you have only one field `foo` then it works as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Query for expected data :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "foo:(John a)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
{
"query": {
 "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "foo",
        "query" : "John a",
         "default_operator" :"or"

    }
  }
}
```

This query returns you the document of it has either "john" or "a".
If you want document if both tokens are present replace default_operator as AND